# The formula of friction

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, friction, models

So I had a question regarding the formula of frictional force (which is $F=\mu N$ where $\mu$ is the coefficient of friction and $N$ is the normal force b/w the objects and $F$ is the frictional force),

The question is:

Is the formula for calculating frictional force just an approximation cause like basically friction on the atomic level is due to regularities right?

So it should be physically impossible to consider each and every irregularities and come up with a simple formula like this one.

**PS:** This is the first question I ever asked on stack exchange so please forgive me if this question is dumb or something

Comment: This formula is mostly a rule of thumb that works reasonably well in quite a few cases, it is not a physical law. There are a lot of friction models that all have their limitations, none as simple as this one though.

Answer (score 1):

The formulas for friction (static and kinetic) are based on empirical models for friction, that is, models based on observation and experimentation. So yes, they are approximations.

For a more detailed discussion, see: http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/frict2.html#kin

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct. The $f=\mu N$ formula is indeed an approximation. Every material will have imperfections.

However, in many cases, the above formula offers a 'pretty good' description of what goes on.

Comment: Of course you can make it a better approximation by assuming that $\mu$ is not a constant, but it is actually a function of the normal force, the relative velocity, the temperature of the sliding surfaces, the phase of the moon, etc, etc. There are models of friction that include more variables (though probably not the phase of the moon!) but they are only useful in computer models, not hand calculations. See chapter 1 of http://www.mate.tue.nl/mate/pdfs/11194.pdf for some examples.